# How do i open a form in access 2007 to show a blank record?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, record

I'm new to access 2007..
I have pressed the save button I want the Staff form to refresh as if I had pressed the button.so its ready for a new record.my problem when i pressed the save button my previous record still displayed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in the button `OnClick` event:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```